Upper bound of operator norm of Hadamard (Schur) product
As in Extension of the Schur product theorem to operators, we can define two compact self-adjoint integral operators $A$ and $B$ on $L^2(\Omega)$, by
$$
A \phi(x)=\int_{\Omega} a(x, y) \phi(y) d y ; \quad B \phi(x)=\int_{\Omega} b(x, y) \phi(y) d y .
$$
Let $A \circ B$ be the integral operator given by
$$
(A \circ B) \phi(x)=\int_{\Omega} a(x, y) b(x, y) \phi(y) d y .
$$
Is it true that
$$
||A\circ B||\le ||A|| ||B||,
$$
where $||\cdot||$ denotes the operator norm ?
A similar conclusion holds true for the matrix case, Proof of Matrix Norm Inequality (Hadamard product), but I got stuck in extending it to the $L^2(\Omega)$ operator case. Can anyone help?

This is not true in general. For example, let $\Omega = [0, 1]$. For any $1 > \epsilon > 0$, let $a(x, y) = b(x, y) = 1_{[0, \epsilon]}(x) 1_{[0, \epsilon]}(y)$. Then $a(x, y)b(x, y) = a(x, y)$, so $A = B = A \circ B$. Thus, $\|A\| = \|B\| = \|A \circ B\| = \| 1_{[0, \epsilon]}\|_2^2 = \epsilon$. However, we do not have $\|A \circ B\| = \epsilon \leq \epsilon^2 = \|A\|\|B\|$. (In fact, this even shows that the bilinear map $(A, B) \mapsto A \circ B$ is not continuous under the operator norm altogether, since no $C > 0$ can exist such that $\|A \circ B\| \leq C\|A\|\|B\|$ for all $A, B$.)

Thanks for your answer!!

@user1247096 Consider accepting the answer if you find it satisfactory. The same goes for the answer to your previous question.
